# trying to copy a .asciiz string to allocated .space in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

im trying to make a simple program that copies a string `soplas` to a .space directive called `buffer`. im getting errors but im not sure where im going wrong, the `beq` statement would be comparing the byte to the 0 ascii character since thats how strings are null terminated, right? copy is called using jal, hence the `jr $ra`  in the done subroutine

```
copy:   
     lb   $t1, soplas($t0) 
     nop
     sb   $t1, buffer($t0)
     nop
     addi $t0, $t0,1
     beq  $t1, 0x00, done
     j copy
     nop
     nop
    
    
done: 
    jr $ra
    nop
    nop
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your C code would look like this:

```
void copy() {
    int i = 0; // start i at 0 to work with soplas[0]/buffer[0]
    while (true) {
        char ch = soplas[i];
        buffer[i] = ch;
        i++;
        if (ch == '\0') break;
    }
}
```

Can you see which line of the C code you're missing in the assembly version?

---

Also, if you're using MIPS with branch delay slots, even `beq` and `bne` need `nop`s, not just `j` and `jr`.

Comment: The other weird thing with the NOPs in the question is that there's one after `sb`.  It only reads registers, not writing any, and has no control-flow effect.  As a bonus, the loop could be scheduled without any NOPs, if one were willing to fill the delay slot after the loop branch with `sb   $t1, buffer-1($t0)`.  Err wait, that's not the loop branch because they're doing it backwards, with a `beq break` instead of `bne copy`.  But it should be the loop branch, then the whole function would only need one.  But that's more advanced than just pointing out that `sb` doesn't have a delay slot.

Comment: sorry @ErikEidt are you referring to initializing the $t0 register? forgot ot mention it but i did outside the subroutine using ```li```

Comment: Ok, that's unusual but can work if all the functions agree on what you're doing.  Otherwise then if that and the delay slots are ok, the problems must be elsewhere in code not shown.